# PHP Jquery Resize blocks hiding the DIV info

Tags: php, jquery, resize, drag

The code in the link below allows you to drag and resize little boxes.  The boxes have text in them but the text isn't showing because it's being covered up by something, which I believe is the resize boxes.  I've tried with no luck to change some settings and tinker with it but can't find anyone that can figure it out.

Why is the info being covered up?

Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/PSdrU38Mi8Z186m8ynMN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are being hidden by the JQuery UI resize `div`s. jQuery UI positions small `div`s at the corners of the `resizable` div, and styles them to be small and margin-less. The problem is this `css` rule:

```
#set div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 90px;
}
```

This is overriding the default `ui` styles for `.ui-resizable-[x]` because they are also `div`s within the `#set` block. Basically, you're inadvertently resizing all the little corner-resize `div`s because your rule applies to all `div`s in the block with the ID of `set`.

Change your rule to:

```
 #set div.resizable {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 90px;
}
```

This will apply the `margin`,`width`, and `height` rules to only the larger div that you're setting as a resizable block, and not to the small `div`s that jQuery UI is creating.